# GraphicsMagick how to resize images from binary data

Tags: meteor, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to use GraphicsMagick to resize the image before uploading to Amazon S3.

I was able to get the binary data of the image file from  like this:

```
        reader.onload = function(e) {

            Meteor.call('s3_upload', file, reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL( file )
```

But the problem is reader.result is not a file URL. It's a binary string data.

How can I take this binary string data and resize it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late response to your question but answering this for anyone who has the same question.

You can resize images before upload with GraphicsMagick from transformWrite option while initializing the Fs.Store

[Image Manipulation](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#image-manipulation) from collectionFS,
here is a snippet from collectionFS S3 [doc](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/tree/devel/packages/s3#client-server-and-s3-credentials)

```
    var avatarStoreLarge = new FS.Store.S3("avatarsLarge", {
  accessKeyId: "ID-HERE", 
  secretAccessKey: "ACCESS-KEY-HERE", 
  bucket: "avatars.large",
  transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('250', '250').stream().pipe(writeStream)
  }
});

var avatarStoreSmall = new FS.Store.S3("avatarsSmall", {
  accessKeyId: "ID-HERE", 
  secretAccessKey: "ACCESS-KEY-HERE", 
  bucket: "avatars.small",
  beforeWrite: function(fileObj) {
    fileObj.size(20, {store: "avatarStoreSmall", save: false});
  },
  transformWrite: function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
    gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('20', '20').stream().pipe(writeStream)
  }
});


Avatars = new FS.Collection("avatars", {
  stores: [avatarStoreSmall, avatarStoreLarge],
  filter: {
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }
  }
});
```